# How can I search with belongsto laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query to search for a username in a store listing is as follows:

```
$data = Store::join('users AS b', 'b.id', '=', 'stores.user_id')
             ->where('b.name', 'like', '%hazard%')
             ->paginate();
```

It works. But I use join to do it.

How can I do it using belongto?

My store model is like this :

```
class Store extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id', ...];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id', 'id');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Store::whereHas('user', function($q) use($username) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$username.'%');
    })->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) package in order to search through the model fields and its relations fields

```
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;

class User extends \Eloquent
{
use SearchableTrait;

/**
 * Searchable rules.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $searchable = [
    /**
     * Columns and their priority in search results.
     * Columns with higher values are more important.
     * Columns with equal values have equal importance.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    'columns' => [
        'users.first_name' => 10,
        'users.last_name' => 10,
        'users.bio' => 2,
        'users.email' => 5,
        'posts.title' => 2,
        'posts.body' => 1,
    ],
    'joins' => [
        'posts' => ['users.id','posts.user_id'],
    ],
];

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}

}
```

use :

```
$users = User::search($query)->get();
```